# Downloading one note page with image content as HTML

Tags: onenote, onenote-api

When we get the page content as HTML using one note API Image sources doesn't seem to be working correctly. There is a $value at the end of the image source in HTML content. How do we handle this when the one note page has images?
Ex:

> img width="649" height="587" src="https://www.onenote.com/api/v1.0/me/notes/resources/0-7dcd564dd9c2472c82451536349be691!1-AA1F36752D8FDBF!14716/**$value**" data-src-type="image/png" data-fullres-src="https://www.onenote.com/api/v1.0/me/notes/resources/0-7dcd564dd9c2472c82451536349be691!1-AA1F36752D8FDBF!14716/$value" data-fullres-src-type="image/png" />>

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried issuing a GET request to that URL (e.g. https://www.onenote.com/api/v1.0/me/notes/resources/0-7dcd564dd9c2472c82451536349be691!1-AA1F36752D8FDBF!14716/$value)? Don't forget to include the Authentication headers.

Comment: Hi Jorge, Thanks for quick response. Don't we have any other way instead of placing a second get request for img SRC?  
If there is page with 10 image  that I wish to display in the app should we parse the html content then look for image source and then fire a new get request to get image?

Comment: I'm afraid with the current state of the API, that is the only possibility.
This uservoice item (vote it and tweet to us if you want this feature!) is related.
https://onenote.uservoice.com/forums/245490-onenote-developer-apis/suggestions/7916235-ability-to-get-pre-auth-d-image-urls-from-a-onenot

Comment: This is now a possibility! See Linda's answer.

Answer (score 2):

Issue a GET request with the following format:

```
https://www.onenote.com/api/v1.0/me/notes/pages/*yourpageID*/content?preAuthenticated=true
```

Essentially, you just pass in the standard query with the argument preAuthenticated=true.