# Unable to render OneNote image resource after appending preAuthenticated=true option in OneNote api call

Tags: azure-ad-graph-api, onenote, onenote-api, microsoft-graph-onenote

https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs/issues/2624

I am experience the issue as the above.

I am trying to save the content of a page with a reference to an image by calling https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{userId}/onenote/pages/{pageId}/content?preAuthenticated=true

Per this - [Downloading one note page with image content as HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35516875/downloading-one-note-page-with-image-content-as-html)

By appending "?preAuthenticated=true" when you do the fetch, it will make the image public.

But when I tried to render the html, it's giving me "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 401 (Unauthorized)".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bit of off topic, but I figured out how to get the image to render.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resource-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

When you call /onenote/pages/{id}/content, the image has a reference to a source like this

src="https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users({userId})/onenote/resources/{resourceId}/$value"  along with data-src-type="image/jpeg"

do a get request to this endpoint and you'll the image binary, convert the binary to base64, and then just render the html by replacing the src with base64.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that something is wrong with the official document: [Get OneNote content and structure with Microsoft Graph](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/onenote-get-content).

We can see that the service root URL is `https://graph.microsoft.com/{version}/{location}/onenote/`.

But in any of the samples on this page, the URL is still `https://www.onenote.com/api/v1.0/me/notes`.

Currently, when you add `?preAuthenticated=true` you will get such a URL for a image on this page:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users('{userID}')/onenote/resources/{resourceID}/content?publicAuth=true&mimeType=image/png
```

But when you try to access it in a browser, you will get `401 error Access token is empty`.

A workaround is to modify the URL to:

```
https://www.onenote.com/api/v1.0/resources/{resourceID}/content?publicAuth=true&mimeType=image/png
```

Then you will get the image.

Comment: Thanks for answering, but still erroring out with:{
  "error": {
    "code": "20130",
    "message": "No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI Resource not found, perhaps the public link has expired. Try a new public page content call..",
    "@api.url": "https://aka.ms/onenote-errors#C20130"
  }
}

Comment: I know. the OneNote api and Graph Api use different token.

Comment: @BenWong In fact, `?preAuthenticated=true` seems to be replaced by Page preview: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/onenote-get-content#page-preview. I have tried with it but the result is the same as `?preAuthenticated=true`. I noticed that you add an answer yourself. You can accept it as answer so this post can be treated as finished.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs/pull/4339/files

I think they removed the support for it.